# How much evidence is needed to support a claim?

Tags: social-psychology, experimental-psychology, behaviorism, experiment-design

Let's say that I hypothesised that if I behave in a certain way (X) then the people I interact with will respond with behaviour (Y). How much evidence do I need to make such claim ?

Comment: You have not stated which form of claim you are making: deductive, inductive, or abductive.   Obviously, Abductive takes the least amount of evidence, and Deductive the most ...  You also might have issues with Bi-Directional influences, (in a closed system).  So ... Are you talking about a one time act, around a stranger?  Or, repeated behavior around known persons?  ***What is the context, and how certain do you want the conclusion to be?***  At that point, we start figuring out a research design and ***reproduction - which is going to be the primary evidence anyway***.